# Expression simplification.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $f(x)=\sqrt{(x+1)^2}-\sqrt{(x-1)^2}$, then one of the following is true:

a) $f(x)=2$

b) $f(x)=2x$

c) $f(x)=2\sqrt{x}$

d) None of the above.

So, lets start then:$$\begin{array}{lcl}
f(x)&=&x+1 - x - 1\\
&=&x-x-1+1\\
&=&0+2\\
&=&2\\
\end{array}$$

I know it's not this easy because $$\sqrt{(x+1)^2}-\sqrt{(x-1)^2} = |x+1|-|x-1|,$$

but how do I simplify this to such an extent that I can eliminate 3 out of 4 given answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|x+1|-|x-1|=$$

$(x+1)-(x-1)=2$ if $x\geq 1$

$(x+1)-(1-x)=2x $ if $-1\leq x\leq 1$

$(-x-1)-(1-x)=-2$ if $x\leq -1$.

Comment: How did you deduce this?

Comment: @Parseval  Observe that $$|x + 1| = \begin{cases} x + 1 && \text{if $x \geq -1$}\\ -x - 1 && \text{if $x < -1$} \end{cases}$$ and that $$|x - 1| = \begin{cases} x - 1 && \text{if $x \geq 1$}\\ -x + 1 && \text{if $x < 1$} \end{cases}$$  Now consider the behavior of the difference in the intervals $[1, \infty)$, $[-1, 1)$, and $(-\infty, -1)$.

Comment: Yes, ofcourse... the definition of absolute value. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

> how do I simplify this to such an extent that I can eliminate 3 out of 4 given answers

- $\;f(-1)=\sqrt{0}-\sqrt{(-2)^2} = -2\;$ eliminates options **a)** and **c)**
- $\;f(2)=\sqrt{3^2}-\sqrt{1^2} = 2\;$ eliminates option **b)**